# Implementing Postgres Sql in Apache Airflow

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, installation, airflow, ubuntu-18.04

I have Apache-Airflow implemented on an Ubuntu version 18.04.3 server. When I set it up, I used the sql lite generic database, and this uses the sequential executor. I did this just to play around and get used to the system. Now I'm trying to use the Local Executor, and will need to transition my database from sqlite to the recommended postgres sql.

Does anybody know how to make this transition? All of the tutorials I've found entail setting up Airflow with postgres sql from the beginning. I know there are a ton of moving parts and I'm scared of messsing up what I currently have running. Anybody who knows how to do this or can point me at where to look is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you should be fine. After installing postgres, create a user/password and update airflow.cfg file accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

Just to complete @lalligood answer with some commands:

In `airflow.cfg` file look for `sql_alchemy_conn` and update it to point to your PostgreSQL serv:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@hostadress:port/database
```

For instance:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@localhost:5432/airflow
```

As indicated in the above line you need both user and database called `airflow`, therefore you need to create that. To do so, open your psql command line and type the following commands to create a user and database called airflow and give all privileges over database `airflow` to user `airflow`:

```
CREATE USER airflow;
CREATE DATABASE airflow;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE airflow TO airflow;
```

Now you are ready to init the airflow application using postgres:

`airflow initdb`

If everything was right, access the psql command line again, enter in airflow database with `\c airflow` command and type `\dt` command to list all tables of that database. You should see a list of airflow tables, currently it is 23.

Comment: in newer versions it's `airflow db init`

Comment: In my case, I had to slightly change the CREATE USER command -

`CREATE USER 'airflow' WITH PASSWORD 'airflow';`

Answer (score 1):

Another option other than adding to the `airflow.cfg` file

is to set the ENV varibale `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` to the postgresql server you want.

Example: `export AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN_SECRET=sql_alchemy_conn`

Or you can set it in your Dockerfile setting.

See documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by doing the following 4 steps:

1. Assuming that you are starting from scratch, initialize your airflow environment with the SQLite database. *The key takeaway here is for it to generate the `airflow.cfg` file.*
2. Update the `sql_alchemy_conn` line in `airflow.cfg` to point to your PostgreSQL server.
3. Create the `airflow` role + database in PostgreSQL. (Revoke all permissions from public to airflow database & ensure airflow role owns airflow database!)
4. (Re)Initialize airflow (`airflow initdb`) & confirm that you see ~19 tables in the `airflow` database.

Comment: I'm installing postgresql. When i enter the command 'psql createdb airflow' to create a database to point to, i get the following error:                                       psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "server.domain.org" (65.254.244.180) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? I read i need to update a directory but cant find it. I'm pretty lost now. thanks