# How do I determine the origin of the Authentication failure in the Airflow PostgresOperator?

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I'm new to airflow. As a first learning exercise I created a minimal DAG that writes a value into a postgres database table every hour. However I fail to establish a connection to the postgres database.

Please note that I'm not talking about creating a postgres backend database to use the Local Executer as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380835/implementing-postgres-sql-in-apache-airflow). That's a different topic (at least the way I understood it.)

I created a minimal example where I:

1. create Linux user, a postgresql role and database all with the same name `minimal_db`
2. create a DAG consisting of one `PostgresOperator`
3. create a connection in the Admin tab of the Airflow webserver

### 1. Creating Linux user, the postgres role and database

For this part I'm relying on [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I logged on the postgres user and created a role called `minimal_db` I created a database with the same name. Next I also created a Linux super user with the same name.
This last step seems unnecessary because I think I don't need *ident* authentication. However it was mentioned in the article I'm following:

> To log in with ident based authentication, you’ll need a Linux user with the same name as your Postgres role and database.

```sh
postgres@ws:~$ createuser --interactive
postgres@ws:~$ createdb minimal_db
gontcharovd@ws:~$ sudo adduser minimal_db
```

Here is the connection info of the database:

```
minimal_db=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "minimal_db" as user "minimal_db" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

I don't know what the socket `/var/run/postgresql` means.

I have created a table called `my_table` and inserted one value:

```
minimal_db=# CREATE TABLE my_table (my_value INT NOT NULL);
minimal_db=# INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (123);
```

I checked that this value is present in `my_table`:

```
minimal_db=# SELECT * FROM my_table;

my_value
----------
      123
(1 row)
```

The postgres server suggests that it accept connections:

```sh
gontcharovd@ws:~$ pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432
localhost:5432 - accepting connections
```

### 2. The minimal Airflow DAG

The DAG I'm using is absolutely minimal: 
Every hour it writes the value 123 into `my_table` in `minimal_db`.

```py
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator

dag = DAG(
    'minimal_example',
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval='@hourly'
)

write_to_postgres = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='write_to_postgres',
    postgres_conn_id='minimal_db_id',
    sql='INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (123);',
    dag=dag
)

write_to_postgres
```

### 3. The Airflow connection created in the Admin tab

Here are the field of the `postgres_conn_id` I'm using in the DAG:

```
Conn Id: minimal_db_id
Con Type: Postgres
Host: localhost
Schema: minimal_db
Login: minimal_db
Password: [same password as the minimal_db role]
Port: 5432
```

### 4. Error during write_to_postgres task

I keep getting a password authentication failure even though I'm sure the password of the postgresql role `minimal_db` matches the password in the `minimal_db_id` connection.

```
[2020-06-05 20:42:51,845] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(PostgresOperator): write_to_postgres> on 2020-06-03T00:00:00+00:00
[2020-06-05 20:42:51,847] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 59141 to run task
[2020-06-05 20:42:51,875] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: minimal_example.write_to_postgres 2020-06-03T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> ws
[2020-06-05 20:42:51,882] {postgres_operator.py:62} INFO - Executing: INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (123);
[2020-06-05 20:42:51,884] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-06-05 20:42:51,884] {base_hook.py:87} INFO - Using connection to: id: minimal_db_id. Host: localhost, Port: 5432, Schema: minimal_db, Login: minimal_db, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: None
[2020-06-05 20:42:51,892] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "minimal_db"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "minimal_db"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.py", line 65, in execute
    self.hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 162, in run
    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py", line 93, in get_conn
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "minimal_db"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "minimal_db"

[2020-06-05 20:42:51,894] {taskinstance.py:1189} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=minimal_example, task_id=write_to_postgres, execution_date=20200603T000000, start_date=20200605T184251, end_date=20200605T184251
[2020-06-05 20:43:01,840] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-06-05 20:43:01,840] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I tried to change the Host field in the minimal_db_id definition to `/var/run/postgresql`. This results in a peer authentication failure instead of a password authentication failure:

```
*** Reading local file: /home/gontcharovd/airflow/logs/minimal_example/write_to_postgres/2020-06-04T18:00:00+00:00/2.log
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,787] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: minimal_example.write_to_postgres 2020-06-04T18:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,793] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: minimal_example.write_to_postgres 2020-06-04T18:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,793] {taskinstance.py:879} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,793] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 2 of 2
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,793] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,798] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(PostgresOperator): write_to_postgres> on 2020-06-04T18:00:00+00:00
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,800] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 64696 to run task
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,836] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: minimal_example.write_to_postgres 2020-06-04T18:00:00+00:00 [running]> ws
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,843] {postgres_operator.py:62} INFO - Executing: INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (123);
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,846] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-06-05 21:25:36,846] {base_hook.py:87} INFO - Using connection to: id: minimal_db_id. Host: /var/run/postgresql/, Port: 5432, Schema: minimal_db, Login: minimal_db, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: None
[2020-06-05 21:25:36,848] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "minimal_db"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.py", line 65, in execute
    self.hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 162, in run
    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py", line 93, in get_conn
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)
  File "/home/gontcharovd/.conda/envs/dateng/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "minimal_db"

[2020-06-05 21:25:36,850] {taskinstance.py:1189} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=minimal_example, task_id=write_to_postgres, execution_date=20200604T180000, start_date=20200605T192536, end_date=20200605T192536
[2020-06-05 21:25:46,786] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-06-05 21:25:46,785] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I don't know what else I can try.

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file for more details on both failures.  "Password: [same password as the minimal_db role]"  You did not describe setting a password for that role.

Comment: Thanks, looking into the logs allowed me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and solution.

My error was that I confused the password of the Linux user `minimal_db` with the postgres role `minimal_db`. I deleted the postgres role and recreated it with an explicit password:

```
CREATE USER minimal_db WITH PASSWORD '123';
```

I specified this password in the connection field of the Admin tab in the airflow web server. Now the values are correctly written to the database.